# Assembly (MASMx86 PC) duplicating array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I'm working on an encryption project that's got me stumped. I need to apply a series of encryption keys to a string array in order to determine which key was used to encrypt the message. I have the code set up to run a loop which applies all keys within the range, but now i need a way to 'refresh' the original string array. My solution was to copy the original array into a new un-populated array of the same size, for each iteration of the loop. I wrote the following procedure to accomplish this:

```
CopyBuffer PROC

; Copies the original buffer into a storage variable
; recieves: nothing
; returns:  nothing
    pushad
    mov ecx,67              ; loop counter
    mov esi,0
L3:
    mov dl,buffer[esi]
    mov bufferCopy[esi],dl      ; Store byte in array copy
    inc esi             ; point to the next byte
    loop    L3
    popad
    ret
CopyArray   ENDP
```

The arrays referred to in the above code were declared as follows:

```
buffer      BYTE    0e9h,0c8h,0d0h,087h,0ceh,0d4h,087h,0d3h,0cfh,0c2h,087h,0d3h,0ceh,0cah,0c2h,087h
            BYTE    0c1h,0c8h,0d5h,087h,0c6h,0cbh,0cbh,087h,0c0h,0c8h,0c8h,0c3h,087h,0cah,0c2h,0c9h
            BYTE    087h,0d3h,0c8h,087h,0c4h,0c8h,0cah,0c2h,087h,0d3h,0c8h,087h,0d3h,0cfh,0c2h,087h
            BYTE    0c6h,0ceh,0c3h,087h,0c8h,0c1h,087h,0d3h,0cfh,0c2h,0ceh,0d5h,087h,0d7h,0c6h,0d5h
            BYTE    0d3h,0deh
bufferCopy  db 67 dup(0)
```

My code successfully populates the duplicate array. However the elements of the copy are different from the corresponding elements of the original array.

I'd really appreciate the wisdom of a more advanced assembly programmer on this one! I'm fairly new to the language, and still a bit fuzzy on syntax.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine to me. There must be something else going on. You are sure you are calling the proc? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems 
You are not using the loop counter that you have created and your loop is just running forever which in turn overwrites your copyBuffer array.
Try the lines

dec ecx
jnz L3

instedof loop L3 that should help.

Comment: The (deprecated) `loop` instruction decrements ecx implicitly (and doesn't branch when it becomes zero).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm curious to know according to who `loop` is deprecated. I was not able to find anything related to `loop` being deprecated in Intel and AMD instruction references. `loop` is also taken into x86-64 instruction set. Do you have some reference on `loop` being deprecated?

Comment: No, I made it up ;) -- Seriously, though, I think I originally got that from [Rick Booth's Inner Loops](http://books.google.com/books/about/Inner_Loops.html?id=v2pnQgAACAAJ) book, which, granted, is getting a bit old. I verified it myself also at the time, but I haven't checked it on recent hardware. I think it has to do with the fact that the instruction is tied to a specific register and thus isn't a RISC-style instruction. Oh, and it's inaccurate to say that it's deprecated - it's just not as fast as dec/jnz (or at least that's how it used to be).

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct (regardless of its untidy style). The only observation is that the provided sample array has only 66 elements, not 67, so the first byte will be copied twice.

The problem is somewhere else. Try to run the program in the debugger and check the array immediately after the return of the procedure in order to proof its correctness.

Comment: I've run through the entire proc step by step. Strangely, both the values of buffer and bufferCopy are shown as 0 '\0' unassigned characters during each step of the procedure. I'm confident that my array was declared correctly, as i am able to print it. Also i changed the loop counter from 67 to 66. Any further suggestions?

Comment: If **buffer** is full of 00h before the procedure call, then there are 2 variants: 1:the data is defined in the uninitialized data section of the program. 2: Your program clears the array somewhere in the code. Unfortunately I am not very strong in MASM syntax (and linker stuff) so can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all thanks to everyone for your suggestions! I've solved the problem (though probably not in the simplest way possible). First of all, i changed the declaration of bufferCopy from

```
bufferCopy  db 67 dup(0)

to

bufferCopy  BYTE    SIZEOF buffer DUP(0),0
```

I think converting to a null terminated string solved some of my problems. Beyond that, i also ammended my CopyBuffer PROC  to run as follows:

```
    pushad                  
    mov  edx,OFFSET buffer              
    Call  StrLength                 
    mov  bufSize,eax                    

    mov ecx,bufSize             
    mov esi,0
L2:
    mov     al,buffer[esi]              
    mov     bufferCopy[esi],al      
    inc     esi                 
    loop    L2
    popad
    ret
```

The call to StrLength was probably a redundancy, considering i knew the length of the string to begin with. As a disclaimer, i'd like to add that i'm not exceptionally familiar with assembly yet. This solution (while functional) is by no means optimal. Furthermore, my explanations are cursory at best.